# How to implement the various globalCompositeOperations in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, light

I'm migrating my project from Javascript Canvas to Javascript WebGL.

In some portions of my code I used Canvas's [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) for things such as lighting and fog.

Now that I am using WebGL I no longer have access to these, but instead have access to [blendFunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendFunc). The global composite operation I am specifically looking to migrate from Canvas to WebGL is `soft-light`, but there are two problems:

1. I don't see that item on the list of blend functions
2. I'm not sure where to find the source for `soft-light`, so I do not know how to emulate it.

I suppose my question is two-part. One, are there any sources that list how the various global composite operations were implemented, and if so, are there any corresponding WebGL implementations? And if not, how can I convert `soft-light` to a WebGL blending function for use in my application?

That is, in Canvas I would do something like this:

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'soft-light';

// draw images

context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'; // reset back to default
```

What would be the equivalent in WebGL? Something like.. (this is close but not accurate)

```
gl.blendFunc(gl.DST_COLOR, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// draw images

gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ZERO); // reset back to default
```

Comment: https://github.com/jamieowen/glsl-blend